# How to add header for dynamic table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

Hello everybody I am drawing dynamic table and I want to add header for table how to add header to dynamic table here is my table code:

```
$.get('http://myDomain.com/RIA/topIndiaDetails.asp', function(data)
{    
    console.log("####"+data);

    var up = new Image();
    var down = new Image();

    up.src = "../../jquery.mobile/images/up.png";
    down.src = "../../jquery.mobile/images/down.png"

    substr = data.split('$');

    //alert(substr.length);
    //var theader = '<table border="1">\n';
    //<table id="auditOverview" border="1">
    var theader = '<table border="1" id=\"tableId\">\n';
    var tbody = '';

    for (var out = 1;out<substr.length-1;out++)
    {
        //alert(substr[out]);
        tbody += '<tr>';
        var pra = substr[out].split('|^');
        //alert('pra.length is: '+pra.length);

        for (var i=0;i<pra.length-1;i++)
        {
            tbody += '<td>';

            if (pra[i]=="Red")
            {
                pra[i].append("<img id='theImg' src='../../jquery.mobile/images/down.png'/>");
            }
            else if (pra[i]=="Green")
            {
                pra[i].append("<img id='theImg' src='../../jquery.mobile/images/up.png'/>");
            }
            tbody += pra[i];    
            tbody += '</td>'  
        }
        tbody += '</tr>\n';
    }       
    var tfooter = '</table>';
    document.getElementById('wrapper').innerHTML = theader + tbody + tfooter;       

});
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you talking about `<th>` in table or something else

Comment: @ CoDe Yes I mean <th>. But when I try to use it I got error.

Comment: @PramodD What kind of error? And using what browser? Bu, above all, what did you actually try?

Comment: Here http://jsfiddle.net/75zFX/6/ what I had tried But if I remove th then table is visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I could get your point correctly

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/75zFX/8/

```
var colheader = '<tr><th>Column1</th><th>Column2</th> .....</tr>\n';
var tbody = colheader ;// and replace with var tbody = '';
```

Answer (score 2):

You can build your header:

```
var header = "<th>...</th>";
```

Then:

```
$("table").append(header);
```

Answer (score 1):

If u want to add Header Manually to a Table,use this code.

**JSP**

```
<th id="example"></th>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$("#example").html("Header Value");
```