# Add table header for dynamic table in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a table in javascript and put a header on it. I tried to incorporate the answer from this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11062735/how-to-add-header-for-dynamic-table) but perhaps I didn't include it in the right place. The body of the table works perfectly, but the header appends as a bunch of text to the top instead of a nicely formatted header. Here is the code:

```
function generate_table() {
    // get the reference for the body
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

    // creates a <table> element and a <tbody> element
    var tbl = document.createElement("table");
    //var header = document.createElement("header");
    var header = '<tr><th>Country</th><th>City</th></tr>';

    //var header = "<th>Header</th>";
    var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");


    // creating all cells
    for (var i = 0; i < results.weak_sent.length; i++) {
        // creates a table row
        var row = document.createElement("tr");

        for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            // Create a <td> element and a text node, make the text
            // node the contents of the <td>, and put the <td> at
            // the end of the table row
            var cell = document.createElement("td");
            if (j == 0) {
                var cellText = document.createTextNode(results.weak_sent_num[i]);
            } else {
                var cellText = document.createTextNode(results.weak_sent[i]);
            }


            cell.appendChild(cellText);
            row.appendChild(cell);
        }

        // add the row to the end of the table body
        tblBody.appendChild(row);
    }
    tbl.append(header)
    // put the <tbody> in the <table>
    tbl.appendChild(tblBody);



    // appends <table> into <body>
    body.appendChild(tbl);
    // sets the border attribute of tbl to 2;
    tbl.setAttribute("border", "2");
}
```

It prints the rows and the columns correctly, but instead of interpreting the `<tr><th>` as HTML tags it just prints them out as text. I've also noticed that if the table text contains any HTML tags, like `<strong>` or `<b>`, they are returned as plain text as well. How can I make them be read as HTML. I have a CSS page as well but there's no reset or anything (intentionally) affecting the use of bold or tables. Here's my result

```
<tr><th>Country</th><th>City</th></tr>
1   Row 1 text
2   Row <b>2</b> text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution1**
The way you are appending tbody rows, you can insert the heading as well. So instead of `tbl.append(header)` and defining the header string, you can use something like below:

```js
results = {
  weak_sent: [
    "row 1 data",
    "row 2 data"
  ],
  weak_sent_num: [1,2]
}
function generate_table() {
    // get the reference for the body
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

    // creates a <table> element and a <tbody> element
    var tbl = document.createElement("table");
    //var header = document.createElement("header");
    // var header = '<tr><th>Country</th><th>City</th></tr>';
    var header=  document.createElement('thead')
    var headingRow = document.createElement('tr')

    var headingCell1 = document.createElement('td')
    var headingText1 = document.createTextNode('country')
    headingCell1.appendChild(headingText1)
    headingRow.appendChild(headingCell1)
    
    var headingCell2 = document.createElement('td')
    var headingText2 = document.createTextNode('City')
    headingCell2.appendChild(headingText2)
    headingRow.appendChild(headingCell2)

    header.appendChild(headingRow)
    tbl.appendChild(header)
    //var header = "<th>Header</th>";
    var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");


    // creating all cells
    for (var i = 0; i < results.weak_sent.length; i++) {
        // creates a table row
        var row = document.createElement("tr");

        for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            // Create a <td> element and a text node, make the text
            // node the contents of the <td>, and put the <td> at
            // the end of the table row
            var cell = document.createElement("td");
            if (j == 0) {
                var cellText = document.createTextNode(results.weak_sent_num[i]);
            } else {
                var cellText = document.createTextNode(results.weak_sent[i]);
            }


            cell.appendChild(cellText);
            row.appendChild(cell);
        }

        // add the row to the end of the table body
        tblBody.appendChild(row);
    }
    // This is for the quick solution
    // tbl.innerHTML = header

    // put the <tbody> in the <table>
    tbl.appendChild(tblBody);



    // appends <table> into <body>
    body.appendChild(tbl);
    // sets the border attribute of tbl to 2;
    tbl.setAttribute("border", "2");
}

generate_table()
```

**Solution2**
As a quick solution you can use innerHTML property, as shown below.

```js
results = {
  weak_sent: [
    "row 1 data",
    "row 2 data"
  ],
  weak_sent_num: [1,2]
}
function generate_table() {
    // get the reference for the body
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

    // creates a <table> element and a <tbody> element
    var tbl = document.createElement("table");
    //var header = document.createElement("header");
    var header = '<tr><th>Country</th><th>City</th></tr>';

    //var header = "<th>Header</th>";
    var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");


    // creating all cells
    for (var i = 0; i < results.weak_sent.length; i++) {
        // creates a table row
        var row = document.createElement("tr");

        for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            // Create a <td> element and a text node, make the text
            // node the contents of the <td>, and put the <td> at
            // the end of the table row
            var cell = document.createElement("td");
            if (j == 0) {
                var cellText = document.createTextNode(results.weak_sent_num[i]);
            } else {
                var cellText = document.createTextNode(results.weak_sent[i]);
            }


            cell.appendChild(cellText);
            row.appendChild(cell);
        }

        // add the row to the end of the table body
        tblBody.appendChild(row);
    }
    // This is for the quick solution
    tbl.innerHTML = header
    // put the <tbody> in the <table>
    tbl.appendChild(tblBody);



    // appends <table> into <body>
    body.appendChild(tbl);
    // sets the border attribute of tbl to 2;
    tbl.setAttribute("border", "2");
}

generate_table()
```

Comment: The second solution works perfectly for me, but the first one prints the Country header above the second column and nothing above the first column.

Comment: @jss367 Thanks for the input, I have edited this. Now both are working